# Emacs fastest C++ compilation process?

Tags: c++, emacs, makefile

Here's the use case: I read an articles on tech blogs about C++
(fails of multiple inheritance this and multi-threading that etc.:).
Usually they come with some code. It's almost always one file and I almost always
want to run it and play around with it.

I want to do it with Emacs and I want to do it FAST,
as in with the least (or reasonably few) keystrokes.

So suppose I've already created a `multiple_inheritance.cc` file in its own folder
and pasted the code. How do I get to an executable really fast?

Here's what I'm doing now (hopefully someone will improve it.)

```
(defun cpp-generate-makefile ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((n-buffer (buffer-file-name))
         (n-file (file-name-nondirectory n-buffer))
         (n-target (file-name-sans-extension n-file))
         (n-makefile (concat (file-name-directory n-buffer) "Makefile")))
    (if (file-exists-p n-makefile)
        (when (called-interactively-p 'any)
          (message "Makefile already exists"))
      (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect n-makefile)
        (insert 
         (concat n-target ": " n-file 
                 "\n\tg++ -g -O2 -std=c++0x -o $@ $^\n\n"
                 "clean: \n\trm -f " n-target "\n"))
        (save-buffer)))))

(defun cpp-run ()
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (cpp-generate-makefile)
  (compile "make"))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
      (lambda()
            ;; ...
            (define-key c++-mode-map [f5] 'cpp-run)))
```

Here's a few things that SLOW me down currently:

1. `compile` asks if I want to save any open files that are totally unrelated to C++.
2. I'd like to have the point in `*compilation*` buffer in case there was an error.
   I've looked into `compile.el`, which has `compilation-num-errors-found` defined,
   but that variable isn't used anywhere in that file.
3. On the other hand, if there were no errors (I just need a predicate for this),
   why not launch `term` and run the program?

Comment: Why do you want point in the compilation buffer?!  It's not required for navigation, just use `M-g n` and `M-g p` to navigate errors.  And why are you generating a Makefile?  GNU Make at least has [implicit rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules) which can [compile C++](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules).  Just use `make CXXFLAGS=<flags> <name>` where `<flags>` are your desired compilation flags, and `<name>` is the name without extension of the file you want to compile.

Comment: Variable `compilation-ask-about-save` is used for asking which buffers to save before compiling.

Comment: @lunaryorn, thanks for suggesting the shortcuts. I had no idea they existed. I was jumping to errors with `C-m` from `*compilation*` before.

About the implicit rules, that's good to know, but it's not as fast as `<f5>`.
Besides, my current script adds a clean target, so I can recursively clean all my
source dirs if I wanted. Also it's a good start if I wanted to add more files.

Comment: Great, @juanleon! That thing's been bothering me forever!

Comment: And you don't need a predicate or an xterm to launch the binary. Just launch it straight from the make command. Just append something like `&& ./a.out` to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the code I had to add a `run` target to `Makefile`.
I've also added an extension to C:

```
(defvar cpp-generate-compiler "g++ -g -O2 -std=c++0x")

(defun cpp-generate-makefile ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((n-buffer (buffer-file-name))
         (n-file (file-name-nondirectory n-buffer))
         (n-target (file-name-sans-extension n-file))
         (n-makefile (concat
                       (file-name-directory n-buffer)
                       "Makefile")))
    (if (file-exists-p n-makefile)
        (when (called-interactively-p 'any)
          (message "Makefile already exists"))
      (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect n-makefile)
        (insert
         (concat n-target ": " n-file
                 (format "\n\t%s -o $@ $^"
                   cpp-generate-compiler)
                 "\n\nclean: \n\trm -f " n-target
                 "\n\nrun: " n-target "\n\t ./" n-target
                 "\n\n.PHONY: clean run\n"))
        (save-buffer)))))

(defun cpp-run ()
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (cpp-generate-makefile)
  (compile "make run"))

(defun c-run ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((cpp-generate-compiler "gcc -g -O2 -std=c99"))
    (cpp-run)))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
      (lambda()
            ;; ...
            (define-key c++-mode-map [f5] 'cpp-run)))
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
      (lambda()
            ;; ...
            (define-key c-mode-map [f5] 'c-run)))
            
(setq compilation-ask-about-save nil)
(setq compilation-finish-functions
      (list (lambda(buffer str)
              (unless (string= str "finished\n")
                (push-mark)
                (next-error)))))
```

With `(setq compilation-ask-about-save nil)` there's no more
warnings about saving (`cpp-run` saves automatically).

And I just have to remember that <kbd>M-g n</kbd> and <kbd>M-g p</kbd>
navigate the errors.

Now my process is neary optimal: one key from source to result in case there
are no errors.

In case there are errors, it's an extra <kbd>M-g n</kbd>.
Now, if only there was a way for `compile` to call  `(push-mark)(next-error)`...

## UPD:

Thanks to suggestion of @juanleon, this is solved with:

```
(setq compilation-finish-functions
      (list (lambda(buffer str)
              (unless (string= str "finished\n")
                (push-mark)
                (next-error)))))
```

But for some reason, `push-mark` doesn't work properly in this case.

Comment: Regarding your last comment... you can use the hook `compilation-finish-functions` to automatically call `next-error` if there are errors.

Answer (score 2):

To sum up the answers in the comments.

1. Change the value of `compilation-ask-about-save`. If you don't want to change this globally (with setq) you can change it just inside your function by wrapping it in a `(let ((compilation-ask-about-save nil)) ...function contents...)` statement.
2. Bind next-error to something quick: `(define-key c++-mode-map "\M-j" 'next-error)`. I personally use global-set-key for this, just because it's useful in a whole bunch of modes.
3. Replace the compile command in your function with `(compile "make && ./a.out")` (using the name of your executable of course).

Hope this helps.