# Why doesn't g++ overwrite executable

Tags: emacs, g++

So I'm trying to emigrate from Windows to Linux. Today I'm trying to code and compile stuff with Emacs instead of Windows IDE's. This is my example code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "HELLO" << endl;
}
```

Which I compiled from emacs using esc-x-> compile-> g++ -o hello hello.cpp

From the terminal, I executed hello using './hello'. Then I changed my code to 'cout << "HOLA FFS" << endl;' and tried to compile using g++ -o hello hello.cpp again. Compilation finished without errors, but when I tried to execute hello from the terminal, the output was "HELLO" and not "HOLA FFS".

Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the accepted answer to this question:

[Emacs fastest C++ compilation process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521232/emacs-fastest-c-compilation-process)

Basically the code from there (which you should paste into `~/.emacs`) will:

1. auto-save your file
2. generate the `Makefile`, if it's not yet there
3. run `compile`
4. if `compile` finished successfully, run the program, otherwise, show first error.

And all of this with just <kbd>f5</kbd>:)

Answer (score 2):

Possible reason is that you did not save you code after you changed your code. I do not think it is necessarily have to do with emacs. Remember to C-x C-s frequently.

Comment: emacs actually prompts for that before compiling, so that's not it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist Hmm...Let me know when you find the solution.

Comment: That's weird. When I edited the code, I think I was actually editing another buffer than the one tied to the original code. So saves to the new buffer didn't affect hello.cpp but some other weird file.

Comment: Yep saving the file simply created a new file called #hello.cpp#, so when I told g++ to compile hello.cpp, it didn't compile my new code. Why in gods name doesn't emacs overwrite the old file instead of creating a new one?!?!

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist Maybe there are multiple buffers opened for the some source file.