# for single file non-interactive c++ programs, print the compile output and output of program(runtime) in same buffer

Tags: emacs

How to compile a single file c++ program, print the output to compile buffer, run the c++ executable if compilation success and append the output of the c++ executable to compile output.

The below elisp code can compile the c++ program with the same name as buffer name. Now how to run and append the output of the exectutable to the **compile**  buffer

```
(defun cpp-single-file-compile ()
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (compile
   (concat "g++ -g " (buffer-file-name) " -o " (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name)))))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key "\C-c\C-c" 'cpp-single-file-compile)))
```

Comment: It's much more flexible to call `make run`. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521232/emacs-fastest-c-compilation-process.

Comment: @abo-abo The requirement of the question in the link is different. since it compiles all the files under the directory by running make. What i need is to simply compile and run the existing file's source code. I have found a simple answer(answer below).

Comment: You've missed a point in the linked question.
You start out with a single c++ file in a directory where there's no Makefile present.
The code automatically generates the Makefile for you and runs it. Afterwards, when your project
is larger than one file, or you want to change some gcc options, you can edit the generated Makefile.
Hence the flexibility. For instance maybe you want to add `-O2`. You edit Makefile instead of
elisp code in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple. Just execute after compilation

```
(defun cpp-single-file-compile ()
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (compile
   (concat "g++ -g " (buffer-file-name) " -o " (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name))
       " && " (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name)) ".exe")))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key "\C-c\C-c" 'cpp-single-file-compile)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, to your code I have a `hack-local-variables` in the `C-c C-c` command:

```
(defun compileCompileCommand ()
  "Compile current file."
  (interactive)
  (hack-local-variables)
  (unless file-local-variables-alist
    (setq compile-command (concat "g++ -g " (buffer-file-name) " -o " (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name))
        " && " (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name)) ".exe")))
    (compile compile-command))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook '(lambda () 
                 (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") 'compileCompileCommand)))
```

Then I add local variables to my source files. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Test";

    return 0;
}

/*
Local Variables:
compile-command: "g++ -g test.cc && ./a.exe"
End:
 */
```

Therewith, you can decide on a per-file basis what you want to do. Changes of the `compile-command` are regarded at the next compilation because of the `hack-local-variables` thing.

The output is:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "/c/temp/" -*-
Compilation started at Fri Nov 15 15:22:34

g++ -g test.cc && ./a.exe
Test
Compilation finished at Fri Nov 15 15:22:34
```

EDIT: Sometimes it is necessary to link some additional library or specify some additional include path. Therefore, I could not accept the answer of Talespin_Kit as a complete solution. I think a combination as it is given in the above edited version is better. If local variables are given then the original `compile-command` is used else an automatically generated `compile-command` is used. Note, one could also use `assq` to check whether `compile-command` is a member of the local variables.

Comment: Editing the source file does not suit my requirement. Thanks for introducing to "Local Variables"(awesomely out-of-box concept).