# compile smart_compile does not generate a executable file

Tags: emacs, compilation

If I create a .c or .cpp file The gcc or g++ compiler will execute and create an executable file from CLI. However; when I run inside of Emacs, either compile or smart-compile command with the same arguments,a NO executable file will be created. If I use chmod +x  to the file, the file won't run.

Comment: Check if the command you give to compile matches the one you give to gcc

Comment: Also, since you don't mention makefiles, you might find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521232/emacs-fastest-c-compilation-process